# How to create a "hard-coded" small SQL join table in code?

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Context: I do not have the ability to create/update/edit the tables in question.

I have two tables that I am trying to join via a manual SQL query in Tableau. There exists a column in each table I can use to link the tables together, but I need a third table (that does not exist) to link them.

There are only 6 values I'd like to link, I was hoping there is some way to declare an "in-memory" table or similar in SQL to join these tables.

For example - I'd like to join these two tables together:

**Table 1**

| name | value |
| --- | --- |
| place 1 | 14 |
| place 2 | 10 |
| place 3 | 100 |

**Table 2**

| identifier | property |
| --- | --- |
| superstore | awesome |
| hospital | bad |
| port | great |

Can I somehow hard-code the following "table" into SQL code to join them?

**hard coded table**

| name | identifier |
| --- | --- |
| place 1 | hospital |
| place 2 | port |
| place 3 | superstore |

Should yield the following:

| name | identifier | value | property |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| place 1 | hospital | 14 | bad |
| place 2 | port | 10 | great |
| place 3 | superstore | 100 | awesome |

If I could create a new table with the linkage above I would, but I can't.

If it's relevant - this is using an Oracle database.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SELECT ... FROM DUAL` and `UNION ALL` to create the data.

It can go in a sub-query factoring (`WITH`) clause:

```sql
WITH hard_coded_table ( name, identifier ) AS (
  SELECT 'place 1', 'hospital' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'place 2', 'port' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'place 3', 'superstore' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT t1.*,
       t2.*
FROM   Table1 t1
       INNER JOIN hard_coded_table h
       ON ( t1.name = h.name )
       INNER JOIN table2 t2
       ON ( t2.identifier = h.identifier );
```

Or just as a sub-query:

```sql
SELECT t1.*,
       t2.*
FROM   Table1 t1
       INNER JOIN (
        SELECT 'place 1' AS name, 'hospital' AS identifier FROM DUAL UNION ALL
        SELECT 'place 2', 'port' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
        SELECT 'place 3', 'superstore' FROM DUAL
       ) h
       ON ( t1.name = h.name )
       INNER JOIN table2 t2
       ON ( t2.identifier = h.identifier );
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Table1 ( name, value ) AS
SELECT 'place 1',  14 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'place 2',  10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'place 3', 100 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE Table2 ( identifier, property ) AS
SELECT 'superstore', 'awesome' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'hospital',   'bad' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'port',       'great' FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

> ```
> NAME    | VALUE | IDENTIFIER | PROPERTY
> :------ | ----: | :--------- | :-------
> place 3 |   100 | superstore | awesome 
> place 1 |    14 | hospital   | bad     
> place 2 |    10 | port       | great
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7a850d9bfb99f198d30425c8c3abb2b7)*

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I obviously had no idea this was a thing. I'll test it out and mark it as answered soon. Out of curiosity, does anything similar to `dual` exist in Postgres?

Comment: @Brandon Yes, just remove the `FROM DUAL` and use `SELECT` without a table [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=9462aca0568ff6065e77f0b005b0a00f). Something similar exists in most RDBMS.

Comment: I wish I could upvote you more than once. Hero.